# How to use sns.jointplot form specific data?

Tags: python, seaborn, jointplot

I want to use jointplot from seaborn. I am using the following code but I do not Understand `sns.jointplot` command. I want in X axis to have g and in y axis to have Years.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
    
df = pd.read_csv('My.txt', sep="\t", header=None)
df.info
print(df)
  
Years=df[0]
date=df[1]
Lat=df[2]
Lon=df[3]
D=df[4]
g=df[5]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sns.jointplot(data=df, x=5 y=0)
```

should work? Otherwise, you will need to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that includes a toy dataset (refer to [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples))